# Where are the authority objects?

Tags: authorization, abap

Any ideas where I can find a list of existing authorization objects? I'm looking for the 'default' ones like `S_CARRID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction SU21.
The S_CARRID object is located inside the BC_C object class.